# How are these URLs highlighting text?

Tags: url, google-chrome, api

I've noticed some web URLs link to a web page with highlighted text. This appears to be controlled by an escape sequence in the URL of the form `#:~:text=StartText,EndText`, where `StartText` indicates where on the page to begin the highlighting and `EndText` is where on the page to terminate the highlighting.

#### Examples

- [https://www.addictivetips.com/internet-tips/select-to-highlight-text-on-web-pages-share-via-url-chrome/#:~:text=Highlighter%20Pen%20For%20Web,paste%20to%20emails%20and%20chat](https://www.addictivetips.com/internet-tips/select-to-highlight-text-on-web-pages-share-via-url-chrome/#:%7E:text=Highlighter%20Pen%20For%20Web,paste%20to%20emails%20and%20chat)
- [https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intraclass_correlation#:~:text=In%20statistics%2C%20the%20intraclass%20correlation,same%20group%20resemble%20each%20other.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intraclass_correlation#:%7E:text=In%20statistics%2C%20the%20intraclass%20correlation,same%20group%20resemble%20each%20other.)

I've seen [query strings](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Query_string) and [named anchors/fragments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2800187/what-is-it-when-a-link-has-a-pound-sign-in-it) in URLs (as per [standard URL syntax](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/URL#Syntax)), but I've never seen escape sequences in URLs -- certainly not like this.

What API/standard/protocol/*etc*. defines/permits/governs this highlighting behavior?

Bonus points for addressing how portable this is. (It works on Google Chrome, but doesn't work in Apple's Safari for macOS.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is called **Scroll To Text Fragment**, and arrived in Chrome 80.

Here is the [draft specification](https://wicg.github.io/scroll-to-text-fragment/), and the [original proposal](https://github.com/WICG/scroll-to-text-fragment).

It seems to me that this is another feature that Google just added to Chrome without other browser vendors signaling any interest (like [Portals](https://medium.com/swlh/portals-in-chrome-going-on-a-test-drive-66b16971fb19), though that one never graduated from being a flag). Here is [an article that calls Scroll To Text Fragment "controversial"](https://www.ghacks.net/2020/02/21/google-implemented-a-controversial-feature-in-chrome/).

Scroll To Text Fragment is [currently available only in Chrome and other Chromium browsers](https://caniuse.com/#feat=url-scroll-to-text-fragment) (e.g. the new Edge).